# Ветовал и бурелом употребляются ли во множественном числе?

Tags: словообразование

Ну, собственно, весь вопрос. Мне вот кажется, что да, так как может быть несколько участков бурелома, а значит, думается мне, они будут не единым буреломом, а буреломами. Или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш вопрос не очень ясен. Что значит "так как ***на*** может быть несколько участков бурелома"? Это собирательные существительные и во множественном числе не употребляются. Кстати, обратите внимание. Правильно: ве***т***ровал, а не ветовал.

ВЕТРОВАЛ, -а; м. Проф.
1.
Поваленные ветром, вывернутые с корнем деревья.
2.
Выворачивание ветром деревьев с корнем.

БУРЕЛОМ, -а; м. ***собир.***
Поваленные, поломанные бурей деревья; участок леса, заваленный такими деревьями. Продираться сквозь б. Забрести в б. < Буреломный, -ая, -ое. Б-ые завалы.
(Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.).

Comment: Да, точно торопился писать. Значит только в единственном числе?

Comment: А как же встреченное мной в СМИ выражение массовые ветровалы? Оно не правильное?

Comment: А-а, вы имеете в виду несколько участков, тогда да, мн.ч. возможно. Мн.число неприемлемо, если говорить об одном участке. Нельзя сказать, например, буреломы (если речь идет об одной территории).

Comment: Большое спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Можно  сказать  так: в  пути   нам  приходилось  преодолевать  многочисленные  буреломы  и  ветровалы.